# How to Making Popup error message from API Server on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Sorry for my bad english,
I just learned flutter dart programming, I want to display a popup when there is an error message from the API server, the debugging status response has come out, but I'm still confused about how to display the popup of the error in my code.

this is my code:

```dart
    Future<QueueModel> getQueue(
    String norm, String dateBirth, String name, String examDate) async {final String apiUrl = "http://192.168.137.99:81/server_api/api/queueme";   final response = await http.post(apiUrl,
      body: {"norm": norm, "dateBirth": dateBirth, "name": name, "examDate": examDate});    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final String responseString = response.body;
    return queueModelFromJson(responseString);    } else{ 
    print(response.body);    }    }
```

Comment: what is your response look like on saving data or if fails to save data @robert

Comment: when "print (response.body);"
I changed it to"return null:" it show error " there is nothing happen"

Comment: Try to handle the usual error code and success code like 404,200 and pass a message object like example `{"status":200,"message":"Data Saved Successfully"}` ,so you can use the `message` in alertbox or you can check the error code in flutter like `if (response.statusCode == 200)` it create a long code if you add more error code@robert

Comment: can you give me a reference to this method sir? i want to learn it...thanks

Comment: Try handling with in flutter https://resocoder.com/2019/12/11/proper-error-handling-in-flutter-dart-1-principles/, try read this also https://dev.to/ashishrawat2911/handling-network-calls-and-exceptions-in-flutter-54me,  and if you are looking for api just search based on the language you used to create API you can use that easily @robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to display it in the app not just output as debug.

For snackbar type of display:

```
void showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String text)
  {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(text),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),//default is 4s
    );
    // Find the Scaffold in the widget tree and use it to show a SnackBar.
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
```

For traditional kind of popups:

```
void showPurchaseDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false, // disables popup to close if tapped outside popup (need a button to close)
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("title",),
          content: Text("your text here"),
          //buttons?
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text("Close"),
              onPressed: () { Navigator.of(context).pop(); }, //closes popup
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, He needs this pop up to come up when the API fails, So @robert call this showSnackBar function in your else part.

Comment: thank you sir, i will try it, yes, i want to popup the error message from API server when there is a fails and not only as debug.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as correct for others.

Comment: `Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);` is deprecated now. Changed that for `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help Jan, I have succeeded in making the response appear on the snackbar